# Probable bug - Embed YouTube video shows an undesired black circle animation near its Title

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

When embedding a YouTube video with the following HTML snippet video appear correctly:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ka-ZgwCXKho?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When instead using the following HTML snippet, a black circle appears for few seconds with animation of type "pulse" near the Video Title inside the YouTube iframe.

```html
    <iframe data-dojo-attach-point="iframeNode" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ka-ZgwCXKho" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

- What is the reason for this behavior?

Notes:

- Same video open directly in YouTube does not present that animation.
- Issue appears on latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I've seen that myself about 10 minutes ago on a forum, but never seen it before. YouTube is doing that, for some reason. Don't waste your time trying to do anything about it for now. Wait and see if it stays, and if it does then what it is.

Comment: Yes I notice this behavior only recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brand new Youtube feature/bug (flashing black circle for 10 seconds after page load) is appearing on all Embedded Youtube Video's.

I have found no information online about it, except this Stack Overflow post.

The only Embedded Youtube videos not affected by this are the ones that:

- have the [parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playsinline) `showinfo=0` (as in your first video, but then no title is displayed).
- have background in upper left dark as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).
- autoplay on page load (no one wants that).

I'm not sure how to tell Google/Youtube to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I had sent a feedback to YouTube using their features "Send Feedback" on their site. If you have time, please report also this bug, hopefully they will have a look at it.

Comment: I didn't find this "Send Feedback" option on Youtube. But I called them and they told me to post on the Youtube help Forum, so I did here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/1pKs2HUBndA;context-place=forum/youtube

Comment: This is Now Fixed apparently... I don't see it anymore